# Existence of quantum states with orthogonal post-measurement states after same measurement outcome

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

Suppose I have two arbitrary quantum states represented by density matrices $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ for system $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Given that I measure each of them in the basis of observable $O = \sum_j \lambda_j |j\rangle\langle j|$, does there exist any $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ such that their post-measurement states $\rho_A',\rho_B'$ are orthogonal (i.e: $\text{Trace}(\rho_A'\rho_B')=0$) given that the measurement outcome for each of them are the same? (i.e: measurement outcome from measuring $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ are both $\lambda_k$)

What is an example of such pair of states if they do exist, how are they orthogonal?

Answers considering the cases of both states being pure states and both being mixed states are much appreciated!

Comment: are you asking for them to have same expectation value on $O$, i.e. ${\rm Tr}(O\rho)={\rm Tr}(O\sigma)$, or for identical outcome probabilities, i.e. $\langle\lambda_j|\rho|\lambda_j\rangle=\langle\lambda_j|\sigma|\lambda_j\rangle$ for all $j$? Also, what are your "post-measurement states"? If you obtain the outcome $j$, it the post-measurement result $|\lambda_j\rangle$? If so, you can have orthogonal post-measurement results with the same identical input state

Comment: I make no assumption on their expectation values and no assumption on their outcome probabilities. In my scenario here $\rho_A,\rho_B$ can be any density matrix. What I'm trying to find out is that if it is possible to have two states $\rho_A,\rho_B$ that were measured in the same basis and gave same measurement outcome, but collapsed to two orthogonal states (i.e: $\rho_A'$ and $\rho_B'$ such that $\text{Trace}(\rho_A\rho_B)$).

Comment: if the measurement outcome is the same, the post-measurement states will also be identical by definition. It doesn't matter if the initial state is pure or not. You are post-selecting/assuming you measured outcome $j$, so the post-measurement state is by definition the corresponding eigenvector of the observable. How are you otherwise defining the post-measurement states?

Comment: That what I was wondering when reading this paper I referred to in my other question that you commented on. From my understanding, the post-measurement state after measurement outcome $k$ should be something like $\frac{|k\rangle\langle k| \rho_A |k\rangle\langle k|}{\text{Trace}(|k\rangle\langle k| \rho |k\rangle\langle k|)}$. Which means that $\rho$ is projected onto $|k\rangle$. I guess I merely misunderstood what the paper meant.